# Javascript works well for DropDownListField but not for RadioButtonList. Where is problem?

Tags: javascript, razor

i have a problem with javascript in cshtml. Works like a charm when i am using DropDownListField.

```
        @Html.Editor("Bod2List", "DropDownListField", new
            {
                items = new List<SelectListItem>() {
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "uvádím v komentářích k jednotlivým ustanovením v návrhu smlouvy", Value = "ne"},
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "chci změnit následující", Value = "ano"} },
                    label = "Vyberte z možností",
                required = true
                })
        
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="Bod2Section" style="display:none">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m["Bod2TextBox"], "StringField", new { placeholder = "Ustanovení (odkaz na čl. a odst. Smlouvy): + požadovaná změna", multiline = true })
    </div>
```

SCRIPT PART:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $("#Bod2List").change(function () {
        var SelectedValue = $('#Bod2List').val();
        if (SelectedValue == "ano")
            $("#Bod2Section").slideDown(300);
        else
            $("#Bod2Section").slideUp(300);
    })

</script>
```

I want to change DropDownListField to RadioButtonList, but when i do my script does not work at all. Could somebody help me?

Many Thanks

Comment: Please share your code snippet for the `RadioButtonList`

Comment: It is the same, i just want to change DropDownFieldList to RadioButtonList in this example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $("#Bod2List").on("change", function () {
        var SelectedValue = $('#Bod2List').val();
        if (SelectedValue == "ano")
            $("#Bod2Section").slideDown(300);
        else
            $("#Bod2Section").slideUp(300);
    })

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for super quick response but unfortunately that does not work. :-(

Comment: in the end you helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Accessing selected value from radio button list is somewhat different compare to that of dropdown list. I hope the below snippet gives an idea...

#### HTML

```html
<select id="idSelectList">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="idRadioList">
    <input type="radio" value="1">
    <input type="radio" value="2" checked>
    <input type="radio" value="3">
</div>
```

#### jQuery snippet to access value

```js
var selectedDropDownOption = $("#idSelectList").val();

// :checked css selector to be used for getting checked radio button
// Without this, the snippet always gives first radio button's value
var checkedRadioButton = $("#idRadioList input[type=radio]:checked").val();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is to much for me. :-) I'm not expert at this at all. I am just changing custom form in our company Service Desk. Coding skills are very limited.

Comment: @cyppisek try to have a look at generated html in client side when rendering `DropDownList` and `RadioButtonList`. Right click on rendered control in page, and click on inspect element. Based on rendered content, the code to access `SelectedValue` changes.

Comment: I tried. What is weird that when i changed the script function and deleted if/else - it will only affect first SelectListItem (Value = "ne") - when i am clicking ond second SelectListItem it does nothing - i am guessing i will stick with DropDownListField...

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it - thanks everyone. :-)

```
$("input[value=ano][type=radio][name=Bod3List]").on("change", function () {
            $("#Bod3Section").slideDown(300);
    })

$("input[value=ne][type=radio][name=Bod3List]").on("change", function () {
            $("#Bod3Section").slideUp(300);
    })
```